# Adding uniqueness restriction to xsd:attributeGroup's attribute

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd, xml-validation

Adding uniqueness restriction to xsd:attributeGroup's attribute.

Current myAttr-group looks like :

```
<xsd:attributeGroup name="myAttr">
        <xsd:attribute name="**name**" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>
```

And later it gets used at multiple places like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SomeComplexType">
    .
    .
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="myAttr"/>
        <xsd:attribue name="more-attr" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        .
        .
</xsd:complexType>        
.
.
```

Is there way to achieve applying of uniqueness constrainst at attribute level rather at element's level?

xml looks something like:

```
<MyRoot>
    .
    .

    <MyComplexTypeElement **name**="abc" value="rr" more-attr="2">Value 1sdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
    <MyComplexTypeElement name="xyz" value="ss" more-attr="22">Value 2asdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
    <MyComplexTypeElement name="some" value="rrr" more-attr="2">Value 3asdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
    <MyComplexTypeElement name="XYZ" value="rr" more-attr="23" >Value 4sdfs</MyComplexTypeElement>

        .
        .

</MyRoot>
```

I checked with `<xsd:unique>` it is possible to achieve only at element level.

Comment: I tried with : 

<xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" >
                    <xsd:unique name="someName">
                        <xsd:selector xpath="MyComplexTypeElement"></xsd:selector>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@name"></xsd:field>
                    </xsd:unique>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>

but doesn't seem to support

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify attribute value uniqueness where the attribute group is *used*, not where it is *defined*.

**For this XML document to be valid:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="abc" value="rr" more-attr="2">Value 1sdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="xyz" value="ss" more-attr="22">Value 2asdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="some" value="rrr" more-attr="2">Value 3asdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="XYZ" value="rr" more-attr="23" >Value 4sdfs</MyComplexTypeElement>
</MyRoot>
```

**But this XML document to be invalid due to a duplicate `name` attribute value:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="abc" value="rr" more-attr="2">Value 1sdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="abc" value="rr" more-attr="2">Value 1sdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="xyz" value="ss" more-attr="22">Value 2asdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="some" value="rrr" more-attr="2">Value 3asdf</MyComplexTypeElement>
  <MyComplexTypeElement name="XYZ" value="rr" more-attr="23" >Value 4sdfs</MyComplexTypeElement>
</MyRoot>
```

**Use this XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:attributeGroup name="myAttr">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="more-attr"  type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:element name="MyRoot">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MyComplexTypeElement" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="myAttr"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="UniqueNameAttr">
      <xs:selector xpath="MyComplexTypeElement"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>   
</xs:schema>
```

**Violations of the uniqueness constraint will yield an error such as:**

```
[Error] try.xml:5:61: cvc-identity-constraint.4.1: Duplicate unique value [abc] declared for identity constraint "UniqueNameAttr" of element "MyRoot".
```

---

**Update per OP's comment:**

> I used above approach, but on violation in my xml , I don't see a
>   error. I am trying to see in IntelliJ ide –  user1587504

The above XML and XSD were tested using known-reliable Xerces-based validating parser.  You can count on it being correct per XSD 1.0.

Things to check:

1. **Use the exact examples as given** first before modifying to your
   particular circumstances to preclude the possibility of an error
   being introduced in application of the concepts.
2. Make sure that the XSD is being associated with the XML.  As a
   sanity check, change the XML's root element to something not in the
   XSD and **check that you are seeing validation errors at all**.

If you still do not receive an appropriate diagnostic message after using the exact example above while having proven that you *can* see other validation errors, you might suspect your tool.  However, a very quick search did not reveal any issues with IntelliJ validation using xs:unique.  In fact, [here is some evidence that IntelliJ does support xs:unique](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t293984-xml-validation-in-intellij.html).

Comment: I used above approach, but on violation in my xml , I don't see a error. I am trying to see in IntelliJ ide